# How can I use regex to search for repeating word in a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to search for a repeating word in a string use regex in **Python**?

For instance:

```
string = ("Hello World hello mister rain")

re.search(r'[\w ]+[\w ]+[\w ]+[\w ]+[\w ]', string)
```

Can I do it so I won't have to repeat `[\w ]+[\w ]`. Can't I just specify `[\w ]*5` instead?

Comment: `\w` is an alphanumeric character rather than a word, but you can specify repetitions with `{5}`.

Comment: I see, so it would be: [\w ]*{5} Correct? Also, is it possible to specify a range (3, 100)?

Comment: same word, or five separate words? How do you define a word, anyways?

Comment: I suppose anything that is Alphanumeric since thats what \w covers separated by whitespace.

Comment: `[\w ]+` alone will match the whole string, Is that what you want?

Comment: You can use regex to either find a word that repeats in the string, or can use it to find 5 words (max) or, can use it to do almost anything. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be easier using plain Python:

```
from collections import Counter

string = "Hello World hello mister rain" # note: no () needed
words = string.split()

for word, count in Counter(map(str.lower, words)).iteritems():
    if count > 1:
        print "The word '{}' is repeated {} times.".format(word, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the first repeating word in a string, you can use:

```
re.match(r'.*(\b\w+\b).*\1', "hello World hello mister rain")
```

`\b` matches the boundaries of a word.

`\1` matches the content of the group defined using `()`

Sorry, but I'm not sure if is this what you want.